# Memoir class - figure and margin figure floats at same vertical level

Tags: floats, memoir, marginpar

In a `memoir` class document, I would like to display a `figure` and a `marginfigure` next to each other but I need the top of the `marginfigure` at the same vertical level as the `figure` next to it.

When I try the following

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure along text}
\end{figure}
\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Margin figure}
\end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

I end up with the top of the `marginfigure` at a lower level than the top of the `figure`:

[image]

When I invert their order in the code, the opposite occurs:

[image]

Is it possible to have the top of both floats at the same vertical level?

Comment: why you not enclose images in the same float environment which has locally increased `\textwidth`. for example with help of the `changepage` package?

Comment: The basic problem here is that the marginfigure is aligned vertically relative to the text in the document, not to the float. Put some text in the MWE above and below the floats to make it clearer what is going on, and also try `\begin{figure}[!t]` for example. As @Zarko said, the only general solution is to combine both graphics into a single float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me elaborate my comment ...

the package `memoir` has integrated functionality of the `changepage` package. for use of its macro `adjustwidth`  for locally change the text width in two side documents is advisable to use the option `strict` which will push smaller image to margin of a page:

```
\documentclass[strict]{memoir}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % for align images in table, ...
\usepackage{tabularx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X @{\hspace{\marginparsep}}p{\marginparwidth}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure along text}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Margin figure}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

why your approach cannot work, see [alephzero](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/72690/alephzero)'s comment above.

Comment: This works great and I did not know about most of what you explained. However, what would I need to do to have another `marginfigure` directly below the "B" `marginfigure`?

Comment: @jrojasqu, you put in comment new question :-). this is not well visible to others which eventually would like to answer you. please edit your question and add new request or (even better) ask new question. also explain how this second image should be aligned (simply below "B"?).

Comment: A new question it is then :)

Comment: @jrojasqu, if the image is only below "B" and hasn't special requirement for align, than just add one more image in the second column, for example:`&   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Margin figure B}
            
    \medskip
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=b]{example-image-c}
   \caption{Margin figure C}`

Comment: Wow, it's that easy... I was setting up another table inside the first table just to add more `marginfigures` below "B" and could not work it out properly. Never crossed my mind to simply skip the line... Thanks a lot!